# How to play a physics animation in a background python script?

Tags: python, animation, scripting, physics, rigid-body-simulation

I'm trying to run a simple physics simulation in my code. The problem is I need to run the script in the background. When I run the following code, I have no issues if Blender is open and I am running the script in the scripting console. However, if I run the script in the background in my terminal, it appears that the animation doesn't actually run (I have checked this by printing the current frame prior to exiting the script).

```
 def stop_playback(scene):
    if scene.frame_current == FRAMES:
        bpy.ops.screen.animation_cancel(restore_frame=False)
    elif scene.frame_current == int(FRAMES/4):
        scene.gravity *= -1
    elif scene.frame_current == int(FRAMES/2):
        scene.gravity *= -1

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(stop_playback)
bpy.ops.screen.animation_play()
```

Additionally, I have tried simply iterating through the frames as is in the proceeding code. However, the animation results of this are terrible, and result in significant object overlap.

```
for i in range(FRAMES+1):
    bpy.context.scene.frame_set(i)
```

So my question is, how can I get the quality simulation I see with `bpy.ops.screen.animation_play()` while still being able to run the script in the background?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: You may need to bake a physics simulation before you can play it depending on the simulation's settings. Have you done that?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had not done that, but I was able to get the latter method to work by simply increasing the steps per second parameter. Still unclear why I was getting such drastically different results to begin with, but in the future will definitely try that.